# How to implement an interface not available at compiletime

Tags: java, reflection

Using reflection, it is possible to implement calls to methods of classes not available at compile time. This is an effective way to make it possible that framework code can work with different library-versions.

Now, say there is an interface

```
interface FutureIntf {
  method1(String s);
}
```

My code does not know this interface yet, but I would like to prepare an implementation for the time, this interface might be made available by the future library version, which needs to work with an implementation of this interface. I want to avoid `javassist`. I think there should be a way using `java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance`, but I did not figure out yet, how to do it effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to retrieve the interface somehow. Then create the proxy as you mentioned with newProxyInstance. Finally you can call methods on the interface or publish the proxy to some service locator or similar.

```
Class<?> unknownInterface = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("bar.UnknownInterface");

Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(unknownInterface.getClassLoader(),
                                      new Class[] { unknownInterface },
                                      new Handler());

unknownInterface.getMethod("someMethod", String.class).invoke(proxy, "hello");
// other way to call it:
// ((UnknownInterface) proxy).someMethod("hello");
```

The Handler class represents the implementation you want to provide:

```
public class Handler implements InvocationHandler {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        if (method.getName().equals("someMethod")) {
            System.out.println("this is the business logic of `someMethod`");
            System.out.println("argument: " + args[0]);
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

What are the downsides here:

- You need to retrieve the Class object of your interface. Probably you need the name of it.
- a) You need to know the names and parameters of the methods
- b) Or if you know the parameter types of the methods you can match them by the types and ignore the names, e.g. `args.length == 1 && args[0].getClass == String.class`

Based on [this tutorial about proxies](https://opencredo.com/dynamic-proxies-java-part-2/)